# MySqlConnection Not Defined

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm developimg a WPF application in `vb.net` which has to connect with a `mysql` database.

I've dowloaded `.NET connector (8.0.11)` from `MySql Website` and I've installed it. Then I've added the reference to `MySql.Data.Dll` in the project references then I've imported the namespace `"MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`.

When I try to lunch my application the `compiler` give me the error `"Type 'MySqlConnection' not defined"`

Please could you help me?

Thank you very much!!

Here Is My Code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient 
Public Class MainWindow 
Public MySqlConn As MySqlConnection 
Public myConnString As String = '*****'

    Public Sub New() 
        InitializeComponent() 
        MySqlConn = New MysqlConnection 
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString = myConnString 
        MySqlConn.Open() 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: May help if you share some code..

Comment: You might want to check your spelling. Maybe you should take notice of what Intellisense tells you as you type.

Comment: I don't think is a problem of spelling. Now I'm trying with an old version of connector and it seems it works...

Comment: You don't think it's a spelling problem? MySqlConn = New MysqlConnetcion

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a connection object as a global variable and keep it around for awhile.  That is a bad idea.  The best practice is to open the connection at the point where it is needed and then close it afterwards.  Let the connection pooling feature do it's job.

Comment: @Honeyboy sorry there was an error done only in this post.. the code is ok.

Comment: It makes it hard to help with your code when you don't show the actual code.